# In MySQL, how to set up a new column in Table1 which pulls in a specific column's COUNT() from Table2?

Tags: sql, mysql

I'd like to put the data returned by the query below into a new column in table `courses` called `total_current_enrollments`. The new column should autogenerate the COUNT() of distinct student_ids by course_id from table `current_enrollments`.

```
SELECT course_id, COUNT(student_id) 
FROM current_enrollments
GROUP BY course_id;
```

```
• TABLE: courses
    • COLUMNS:
        o id INT AI PK
        o title VARCHAR(100) NN
        o number_of_credits INT
        o course_code VARCHAR(10)
        o lecturer_id INT
    
• TABLE: current_enrollments
    • COLUMNS:
        o Id INT AI PK
        o course_id INT NN
        o lecturer_id INT
        o student_id INT
```

How should I set up my new column to achieve this?

Maybe a default/expression will do the trick.

Comment: You must use a trigger.

Comment: consider using [a view](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/views.html) to achieve this kind of behavior, rather than actually storing the COUNT in a table.

Comment: Why are you want to store rows count in the separate table? What should happened if somebody will add new row into the `current_enrollments` table? or delete? Why can't you use just your select or view?

Comment: Also see: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/202758/bad-practice-to-store-calculated-data-in-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to use a `DEFAULT` or a generated column to do this. Those features can't query another table.

Refer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html:

> ...
>
> - Subqueries, parameters, variables, stored functions, and loadable functions are not permitted.
>
> ...

Refer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html:

> ...
>
> - Subqueries are not permitted.
> - A generated column definition can refer to other generated columns, but only those occurring earlier in the table definition. A generated column definition can refer to any base (nongenerated) column in the table whether its definition occurs earlier or later.
>
> ...

You have three options:

Option 1: Define a set of triggers on the `current_enrollments` table. When a row in `current_enrollments` is inserted, then an INSERT trigger increments the count column for the respective course. When a row is deleted, then a DELETE trigger decrements the count column of the respective course. When a row is updated, then check if the course has been changed, and if so, decrement the old course and increment the new course.

In theory, this should keep the course enrollment counts in sync, but in practice it tends to get out of sync. This is mysterious, but it happens.

Option 2: Define a view that queries the `courses` table, joins to the `current_enrollments` table, and uses `COUNT(*)` to count the enrollments. This is bound to be more accurate, but it can be a performance drag.

Option 3: Keep the counts updated through application logic. In my experience, the best way is to just recalculate the counts by running a query like the one in the view every N minutes, and update the `courses` table. This means there is often a delay between an enrollment and the update of the `courses` table. But if enrollments are infrequent, then the counts are accurate more than 99% of the time.